# Tkinter GUI reopens when using pyplot later in code

Tags: python, macos, python-2.7, matplotlib, tkinter

I created a Tkinter GUI and as a standalone code it closes successfully, but when I try to open an unrelated figure using matplotlib.pylplot, the GUI reappears.  An shortened version of the  code used is below for brevity (issue still present) and I am running this using python 2.7.14 on MacOSX

```
from Tkinter import *

def gui():

    root = Tk()
    frame = Frame(root)
    frame.place(x=600,y=600)

    label = Label(root, text="Folder for")
    label.place(x=30,y=160)
    button_exit = Button(root,
                         text="Exit",
                         command=root.destroy)

    button_exit.place(x=320,y=280)

    root.geometry("600x350")
    root.attributes("-topmost", True)
    root.mainloop()
gui()
import time

time.sleep(1.5)

from matplotlib import pyplot
figure = pyplot.figure()
pyplot.show()
```

Comment: `root.destroy()`. I guess there are many questions on how to exit a tkinter program, right?

Comment: I use root.destroy if you look at the exit command.  After I use root.destroy, the GUI exits sucesffiuly, but when I inititate pyplot.show() it reappears

Comment: I see. Could be a mac problem, because I cannot reproduce it. I edited the tags.